# Download the portlet 2.0 api

Tags: java, portlet

Can anyone tell me where I can download the portlet 2.0 api from?

Comment: In order to implement the API yourself or to use the API (with a 3rd party implementation)?

Answer (score 1):

Specification: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr286/index.html

For the JARs containing the APIs - well, those normally aren't published by Sun (well, Oracle now). They're usually shipped as part of J2EE containers: Sun / Oracle publishes the spec, and someone from the J2EE container's vendor (say, IBM) prepares a JAR according to the spec.

Here's JBoss':

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [maven repository](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0/).